# Selecting line ID for records with a distinct combination of two fields

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm working in Microsoft Access, and I have a table like this:

[image]

I only want to select ID values when the combination of fName and Lname appear for the first time.

So for this example I want my select statement to return 1 2 3 6 7 8 and leave out 4 5 9.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a min for id and group by  for fname and lname

```
select min(id), fname, lname 
from my_table
group by fname, lname
```

Comment: I believe this worked. Though I only wanted the ID field to show. So I changed it to:

SELECT min(ID)
FROM my_table
GROUP BY fName, lName

Answer (score 0):

You could use `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY fName, lName ORDER BY id) AS rn 
     FROM tab) sub
WHERE rn = 1;
```